# Android most efficient container for list purpose

Tags: java, android, android-layout

(*P.S. I am new to android development, so would appreciate a bit consideration.*)

My test app includes a custom view which looks like the following :

[image]

(*I won't be including the XML code of this view, as it would make the post unnecessarily big*)

This custom view has a `LinearLayout` as a root element. Within the `LinearLayout` there are 2 more nested `LinearLayouts`. Even though it may seem like `RelativeLayout`s can be used at first, after trying all the containers only the `LinearLayout` could achieve this look.

The problem is that I need to dynamically populate a list of my custom view (the above one). It can range from 40-80. I tried to dynamically generate 60 of the above custom views in my test environment as children of a `RecycleView` inside a `ScrollView`.

In my test environment, on my physical device(Samsung Galaxy J2) I can see that the performance of the app degrades a bit but not too much. Still, I can see that the app is using too much of device memory.

I have been through a lot of SO posts on layout performances. From the docs I found out that using too many nested `LinearLayout`s can crate a deep and complex view hierarchy. So, I tried to use `FrameLayout`, `RelativeLayout` whereever I could.

My scenario is not unique actually. If you are a developer who's reading this and have some experience with developing some big apps, you most certainly have scenarios where you need to dynamically generate a custom view a lot of times. So, what would be the advice here? 
In apps like Facebook or even Facebook Lite, or other apps that have similar custom views populated in bulk, which layouts do they actually use to ensure optimal performance? And given my scenario, is my approach correct ?

Comment: `RecyclerView` is made for large lists, you're just not supposed to use it as `ScrollView` child as this can lead to measurement issues.

Comment: @Pawel, okay. But let's say, i remove the `ScrollView`, but still then, my main issue persists. The app would use too much memory. Or am i wrong ?

Comment: If you properly implement `RecyclerView` it should only create enough views to fill the viewport and re-use them as you scroll. It's actually very memory efficient.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Whenever you use `RecyclerView`, it only creates Views enough to fill the screen/viewport of the device. Other all the views are only "Recycled", meaning, the views will be reused again and again,but only with new data.

The lag you might be experiencing, is because of the `ScrollView` on top of the `RecyclerView`. Your RecyclerView shouldn't lag unless you're using heavy images without using Glide/Picasso for image loading.

Comment: Thanks for that! I guess that would do it. But my question still remains. As i am using `LinearLayout`s in my custom views, is that ideal ?

Comment: Yes, LinearLayout's in RecyclerView is not a big deal unless you're doing crazy layout_weight measurements on child views, or creating Views that overly complex. I have app with thousands of user submissions, and there's no lag while scrolling through the data.

Comment: But does your app use too much device memory?

Comment: if you want optimization for views you can use constraint layout. linear layout will also do the trick if you dont have complex/ nested view hierarchy.

Comment: No. It never uses crazy device memory. Only memory that it might use is to store the objects from the arraylist(details which are fetched from server). Most of the memory in Android is gone to the UI part, rest of the memory that is used is negligible.

Comment: Also, another reason for lag in your case must be how you're using the bottom right bulb icon. If it's a huge icon, and just added in your layout `ImageView` with `android:src="@drawable/bulb"`, then it'll cause some lag. You can use Image Loading libraries like Glide to load Images in your ViewHolder.

Comment: No, it's an 80X80 png, with a file-size of nearly 150bytes, And the `ImageView` itself is just 40dp X 40dp, would that cause any issue tho ?

Comment: It shouldn't cause any issue, but you should still use Glide for efficient memory management in bitmaps. You know how to use Glide right? It's the most important thing to learn when you work with images. I learnt it the hard way!

Answer (score 0):

RecyclerView is a ViewGroup added to the android studio as a successor of the GridView and ListView. It is an improvement on both of them and can be found in the latest v-7 support packages. It has been created to make possible construction of any lists with XML layouts as an item which can be customized vastly while improving on the efficiency of ListViews and GridViews. This improvement is achieved by recycling the views which are out of the visibility of the user. For example, if a user scrolled down to a position where the items 4 and 5 are visible; items 1, 2 and 3 would be cleared from the memory to reduce memory consumption.

Comment: Yeah, i acknowledge that now. However, your answer should be more informative for future readers.